# Is there a way (or plugin) that condenses empty parent packages (folders) in SublimeText3?

Tags: sublimetext3

We often have empty parent packages (or folders), e.g., a class hierarchy such as `src.main.scala.com.acme.app...` represents an essentially empty folder structure:

```
src
  + main
    + scala
      + com
        + acme
          + app
            Class.scala
            AnotherClass.scala
          + ui
            SomeForm.scala
```

IDEA has a nice feature wherein it will automatically condense the folder structure, so rather than drawing out the above you get something like this:

```
src.main.scala.com.acme
  + app
    Class.scala
    AnotherClass.scala
  + ui
    SomeForm.scala
```

This is a really nice space saver and makes it easier to navigate the directory tree. Is there such a feature / plugin available for SublimeText3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Sidebar doesn't have the ability to display files in a format other than the usual file tree and there is not currently an API that allows for a plugin to change anything about how the sidebar is displayed either.

It would be possible for a plugin to gather the list of files that are being display in the side bar by querying the file system directly and then display them in a temporary file view of some kind.

A barrier here is that the Sublime API also doesn't have an API that exposes the index of project files to you in a way that would allow you to leverage its inherent knowledge of all of the files in the project, so the plugin would have to also keep the file list up to date on its own.

Along with that it would also have to replicate other functionality of the sidebar; for example folding of folders or context menu items.

That said I'm not aware of any existing package or plugin that provides that level of functionality and a [search](https://packagecontrol.io/search/sidebar) of [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) doesn't turn up anything. The [FileBrowser](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileBrowser) package implements this set of features (but not the flattening as far as I'm aware); it may be worth digging and/or making a feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @OdatNurd.